# preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 203 runescape

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Can someone please tell me why this wont work?

I am getting error "preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 203"

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/results.ws?query='.urlencode($term).'&price='.$pricerange.'&members='.$members);
$html = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $html);
$regexp = '#<tr data-item-id="(.*?)"><td class="(.*?)"><img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)"><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a></td><td><img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" title="(.*?)"></td><td class="(.*?)">(.*?)</td><td class="(.*?)">(.?*)</td></tr>#';
preg_match_all($regexp, $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Example url that would be used in the file_get_contents

```
http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/results.ws?query=gold%20bar&price=all&members=no
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of the full url that are inside the `file_get_contents` ? Without it, we can't help you.

Comment: I'd suggest to use [DOM](http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of regex. It's much more reliable.

Comment: have added an example full url for the file_get_contents :)

Comment: `(.*?)` - the worst thing in the RegExp. Works slowly, use `([^"]+)` for attribute's values matching instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest your error is right here :

```
<td class="(.*?)">(.?*)</td></tr>#
```

Replace by

```
<td class="(.*?)">(.*?)</td></tr>#
```

Comment: thank you so much for that, cant believe I missed that error. I feel so silly now lol. But thank you for helping me :)